# How can I use set_fact and with_together?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am trying to convert bash environment variables that are sourced from a properties file on a remote machine. I am registering the keys and values to two register variables and then trying to loop through them using `with_together` and `set_fact`

Here is how I am sourcing my variables key/values

```
- name: Source Env Properties
  shell: . <source utility> && ( set -a posix ; set| sed 's,=.*,,' )
  register: variable_keys

- shell: . <source utility> && ( set -a posix ; set| sed 's,^.*=,,' )
  register: variable_values
```

After that I try to `set_fact` using the two registered values.

```
- name: set variables
  set_fact:
     "{{item.0}}:{{item.1}}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ variable_keys.stdout_lines }}"
    - "{{ variable_values.stdout_lines }}"
```

The output of the tasks seems like it should be working but when trying to use those variables it says they are not defined.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: I think you have too much quoting in your `set_fact` block.  Try `"{{item.0}}": "{{item.1}}"`?

Comment: @larsks same results. No errors until I try to use one of the facts as a variable later in the playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your first problem, as I alluded to in my comment, is that the syntax in your `set_fact` block is incorrect.  If you have this:

```
"{{item.0}}:{{item.1}}"
```

Then you have single string, not a `key: value` pair.  You would need to modify that to look like

```
- name: set variables
  set_fact:
    "{{item.0}}": "{{item.1}}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ variable_keys.stdout_lines }}"
    - "{{ variable_values.stdout_lines }}"
```

But that's only half the problem.  Your `sed` expressions may end up producing syntactically invalid output, because they will include bash function definitions. That is, if I run the first command in my local environment, the output includes all the cruft from shell functions for bash completions, git prompts, etc, like this:

```
scl () 
{ 
    local CMD
    if [ "$CMD" 
        eval "module $@";
    else
        /usr/bin/scl "$@";
    fi
}
```

That's just going to break ansible:

```
failed: [localhost] (item=[u"'", u"'"]) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": ["'", "'"], "msg": "The variable name ''' is not valid. Variables must start with a letter or underscore character, and contain only letters, numbers and underscores."}
```

You'll need to make sure you filter out that content.  I used this:

```
- name: Source Env Properties
  shell: . ./myvars.sh && ( set -a posix; set| sed -n '/^[A-Z]/ s,=.*,,p' )
  register: variable_keys

- shell: . ./myvars.sh && ( set -a posix; set| sed -n '/^[A-Z]/ s,^.*=,,p' )
  register: variable_values

- name: set variables
  set_fact:
    "{{item.0}}": "{{item.1}}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ variable_keys.stdout_lines }}"
    - "{{ variable_values.stdout_lines }}"
```

If I have have, in `myvars.sh`:

```
FOO=bar
```

And if in my playbook I have, after the above:

```
- debug:
    var: FOO
```

I will see as output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "FOO": "bar"
}
```

Incidentally, I think all this mucking about with `sed` is fragile and may cause other problems down the road.  I would probably do something like this:

```
- name: Source Env Properties
  shell: |
    set -a
    . ./myvars.sh
    jq -n env
  register: vars_raw

- set_fact:
    shellvars: "{{ vars_raw.stdout|from_json }}"

- debug:
    var: shellvars.FOO
```

This uses `jq` to export all available environment variables as JSON, and then assigns the result to the `shellvars` variable.  The `set -a` there assures that any variables set in `myvars.sh` are exported to the environment. If you don't have `jq` handy, you could use `python`:

```
- name: Source Env Properties
  shell: |
    set -a
    . ./myvars.sh
    python -c 'import json; import os; print(json.dumps(dict(os.environ)))'
  register: vars_raw

- set_fact:
    shellvars: "{{ vars_raw.stdout|from_json }}"

- debug:
    var: shellvars.FOO
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are right mucking about with `sed` is problematic down the road but the tweak you provided to my `sed` fixed my issue for now. The python solution also could work in most of my environments but not all of them.